# "In what that sense"

Tags: word-meaning

In the following passage:

> Understanding what heuristics people use to make these essential metacognitive judgments is essential if we are to understand how people gain and maintain a sense of agency, and, in what that sense consists.

What does "in what" or "in what that sense" mean?
Is it correct grammar to write "in what that sense consists"?

Answer (score 1):

It is a convoluted sentence, partly because it uses a relatively unfamiliar collocation *consist in*: see sense 3 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consist#Etymology_1).

In a less formal context it would be written:

> and what that sense consists in.

but many people feel that it is more formal not to end the relative clause with a preposition ("in") and instead put it before the relative pronoun.